# MongoDB using mongoose for populate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am having collection1 with one of the column as ref of collection2. Now i want to populate(join) collection1 and collection2 with some condition on collection2 fields. Is it possible?

What i want to do is

```js
models.Encounter        
    .where('practice').equals(practice)
    .populate({
         path:'chart',
         match:{firstName:{ $regex: new RegExp(Name.toLowerCase(), 'i') }},
         select:'firstName lastName'})
    .populate('provider', 'firstName lastName')
    .populate('signedBy', 'firstName lastName')
    .sort('-date')
    .limit(100)
    .exec(function (err, encounters) {})
```

Here charts is collection and for me match is not working..Where Name comes from jade engine. null values are coming for firstname
Practice Schema:
The schemas are

```js
var practiceSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
  name:                String,
  internalName:        String,
  address:             addressSchema,
  phone:               String,
  taxId:               String
});
```

Chart Schema:

```js
var chartSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
  created:             Date,
  updated:             Date,
  practice:            {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'practices', required: true},
  mrn:                 String,
  firstName:           String,
  lastName:            String,
  emailWork:           String,
  phoneHome:           String,
  phoneMobile:         String,
  dob:                 Date,
  married:             Boolean,
  smoker:              Boolean
});
```

Now i want to get data from Encounters by populating charts and also charts.firstName == 'XYZ' and charts.lastName == 'ABC'.. I have done this by getting all data from encounters and then applying filter on charts. But it is taking too much of time..

Comment: Can you update your question to include the schemas for the two collections and a specific example of what you're looking to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to protect the password field in Mongoose/MongoDB so it won't return in a query when I populate collections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096262/how-to-protect-the-password-field-in-mongoose-mongodb-so-it-wont-return-in-a-qu)

Comment: .populate({
path: 'contributors',
match: { email: /@theholmesoffice\.com/i },
select: 'name lastLogin',
options: { limit: 5, sort: 'name' }
})
.exec() I want to do something like this..