# How do you add options to a schema property in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Say that my Schema is:

```
var fooSchema = new Schema({
  foo: String
});
```

and I want to add `select: false` to `foo`. How would I do that? Without doing the following:

```
var fooSchema = new Schema({
  foo: { type: String, select: false }
});
```

Can I do `fooSchema.<somethingToAddSelectFalseToFoo>`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this would work: Mongoose schema.set() function: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-set.

```
Schema#set(key, [value])

Sets/gets a schema option.

Parameters:

key <String> option name
[value] <Object> if not passed, the current option value is returned
```

fooSchema.set('foo', { select: false });

In a select query you could exclude it, i.e. fooSchema.find().select("-foo"). Some examples are at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12097874/442472.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in the docs but I didn't understand. Could you confirm/explain?