# Access "select: false" fields in mongoose.Schema.methods

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Working with a toy example, lets say I have the following Schema:

```
const ExampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  publicField: String,
  privateField: { type: String, select: false }
});

ExampleSchema.methods.doSomething = async function() {
  console.log(this.privateField); // undefined
}
```

How do I access the `privateField` in the `doSomething` function?

Or is there a better to achieve this?

Comment: Please look at this link...https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1596 .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096262/how-to-protect-the-password-field-in-mongoose-mongodb-so-it-wont-return-in-a-qu

Comment: hmm makes sense. Currently, I'm using that workaround of selecting the whole object and then deleting the sensitive fields in the `.toObject()` function

Answer (score 0):

The `privateField` is accessed correctly for `doSomething` instance method in your schema definition.

The `ExampleSchema` makes the `doSomething` method available on the `Model` using it.

`this.privateField` refers to the `privateField` property of the model instance.

Lets say there is an `Example` model that uses `ExampleSchema` definition

```
const Example = mongoose.model('Example', ExampleSchema);
```

When an instance of `Example` is constructed, it will have `doSomething` method available on it.

```
const example = new Example({privateField: 'This is a privateField'});
example.doSomething(); // logs "This is a privateField"
```