# How to hide a field in the callback of document.save() in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want display the data of a user after its been created, returning the user inside a async function using the following code:

`const newUser = await user.save()
 return newUser`

But I don't want it to be possible for the password to be seen.

I've already encountered [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096262/how-to-protect-the-password-field-in-mongoose-mongodb-so-it-wont-return-in-a-qu) which contains a similar issue, and the best approach presented there is by placing `select: false` inside the password field of the schema definition. It works for find functions, but it doesn't for the document.save() callback.

Currently I'm achieving what I want by using a spread operation and resetting the password field:

`const newUser = await user.save()
 return { ...newUser.toObject(), password: null }`

Is there a better approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11), it is better library with clean code

```
return _.omit(newUser, ['password']);
```

or second thing you can use post save on schema level

```
schema.post('save', function(doc) {
  delete doc.password;
});
```