# mongoose schema contains entire DB object instead of defined schema object

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using two schemas for users. One that contains the password/salt, one that doesn't for returning to the front end. When I use the model that uses the schema WITHOUT the password, it still returns the password :/

Generic User (For sending to the client)

```
module.exports = {    
    username: String,
    email: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    createdOn: Date,
    updatedOn: Date,
    scopes: [String]
}
```

Auth User (for creating/updating/authenticating users)

```
module.exports = {    
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    salt: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    createdOn: Date,
    updatedOn: Date,
    scopes: [String]
}
```

Creating the models with

var modelInstance = mongoose.model("authUser", authUserSchema, 'users')

(in a different file)

var modelInstance = mongoose.model("user", userSchema, 'users')

modelInstance is exported with 
module.exports = modelInstance;

**Update** This question answers mine.
[How to protect the password field in Mongoose/MongoDB so it won't return in a query when I populate collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096262/how-to-protect-the-password-field-in-mongoose-mongodb-so-it-wont-return-in-a-qu)

Comment: Are you persisting both of these? i.e. two entries for each user ?

Comment: Well both models represent the same collection `users` It is going to return you the fields whichever model u execute the query from. To restrict the field [there are various ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096262/how-to-protect-the-password-field-in-mongoose-mongodb-so-it-wont-return-in-a-qu) prevent select the `password` field when you query from Model of `userSchema`. Also assuming that you are following *One schema/model per file* structure in node

Comment: @ambianBeing That link was what I needed. I just wasn't searching for the right thing earlier :( But it's good to have variations of questions like this b/c not everyone will approach the problem the same.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a clear question, but I guess you are asking if you can restrict it. The answer is 'no' by default.

There is a plugin for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-strictmodel
But it's really out of date.

It's easy enough though to create a wrapper function:

```
function safeUser(userModel) {
  return {
    username: userModel.username,
    email: userModel.email,
    firstName: userModel.firstName,
    lastName: userModel.lastName,
    createdOn: userModel.createdOn,
    updatedOn: userModel.updatedOn,
    scopes: userModel.scopes
  }
}
```