# Getting an array inside a nested JSON using $http.get (mongoose with nodejs)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this JSON which represents an apartment listing:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5673d1dcf93fe452d80c2c2c"
    },
    "street": "myStreet",
    "buildingNumber": 1,
    "apartmentNumber": 1,
    "UsersAndQuestions": [
        {
            "userID": "5673afe4cb62303816bd3d5c",
            "questionID": [
                "5669d90a058ceddc158e97e2",
                "4668d80b158ceggc158e97f2"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get the `questionID` array of a certain `userID`.

I am using this `http.get` to try and get it:

```
app.get('/api/listing/getQuestionsOfUserInListing/:userid/:listingid', function (req, res) {
        var user = req.params.userid;
        var listing = req.params.listingid;
        Listing.find({
                $and: [
                    {_id: listing},
                    {'UsersAndQuestions.userID': user}
                ]
            }
            , function (err, result) {
                res.json(result);
            });
    });
```

But I'm just getting back the **whole** JSON (exactly the one I posted in the beginning of the question).

How can I get just the
 `"questionID": ["5669d90a058ceddc158e97e2", "4668d80b158ceggc158e97f2"]` ?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548186/mongoose-use-of-select-method

Comment: Thanks @Wesley, I'd love to see an example of use which is somewhat applicable to my case. In the question you shared they don't really show any

Comment: Perhaps reading the documenation will help? http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection) you can do it with such projection:

```
Listing.findOne( {_id: listing, 'UsersAndQuestions.userID': user}, 
    {_id: 0, 'UsersAndQuestions.$': 1}, 
    function (err, result) {
        res.json(result.UsersAndQuestions[0].questionID);
    });
```

P.S. Also I don't see any reason why you need to use $and operator here. From [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/query-documents/):

A compound query can specify conditions for more than one field in the collection’s documents. Implicitly, a logical AND conjunction connects the clauses of a compound query so that the query selects the documents in the collection that match all the conditions.