# mongodb: one getAllData query VS more getSingleField queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I'm using NodeJS with Mongoose. I have a collection 'user' with a schema like the following:

```js
 id: String
 name: String
 surname: String,
 otherField1: Number,
 otherFieldN: String,
 arrayField: [String],
 messages:[
        {
            date: SchemaTypes.Long,
            id: String,
            type: String,
            content: String
        }
    ],
status:String
```

Supposing I have more than 10K users into my collection, what's the best way to query it if I have a function that needs in different moments some (not all) information of a single user? Is it better to query all the user data in a single query and use them locally when they are needed or is it better to query only the needed field doing more than one queries into the same function?

I precise that in the second case (more queries), depending on the result of the first queries will change the fields needed by the succeeding ones

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should make the query upon the function needs to get the information about the user.
That way you don't need to save things locally.

Answer (score 0):

From MongoDB perspective there is no difference performance wise:
you will hit the same number of documents with or without the chaining of `.select({fields you need})` since it's the query in the find that matters (see the [Explain command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) for more info on how to analyze query in mongodb).
 To improve performance on Mongo you need to [create an index](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-index/) in your collection on the most used field you query on or eventually [shard among instances](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/).
The big impact in your case is on the Node memory side: using `select` is suggested if you don't need other fields *in the close future*; of course if you need to re-query the DB for the other fields right after then makes sense to not  use select, but keep the whole user object on the first place.
**Note:**
from Mongoose 4.0+ you can avoid the explicit use of the `select` command [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9549489/2408863).