# Returning particular arrays from objects in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
[
  {
    _id: 555,
    names:['John','Doe','David']
  },
  {
    _id: 625,
    names:['David','Mark','Carl']
  },
  {
    _id: 299,
    names:['Bill','Carlos','Ventus']
  }
]
```

How can I return only the names(object) of all the object having _id in MongoDB ?
Please help me..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select a single field in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589113/how-to-select-a-single-field-in-mongodb)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548186/mongoose-use-of-select-method

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html try to use `select`

Answer (score 0):

```
model.find({_id : { $exists : 1} }, "-_id names", { lean : true })
```

As each document in mongoDB has _id : `model.find({}, "-_id names", { lean : true })` this would be fine.

You could also use mongo aggregate as follows :

```
model.aggregate({ $project : { _id : 0, names : 1 })
```